# Issue Blueimp gallery Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Blueimp gallery to present some images on my website. There are 8 images divided in two rows. The 5th thumbnail (first image on the second row) seems broken, although I can see it in the carousel presentation.

![thumbnails]:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByO6EWQ4CgAUaGwzbXhnWDlBWFU/view?usp=sharing

Here's the code

```html
<!-- The Gallery as lightbox dialog, should be a child element of the document body -->
   <div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls">
       <div class="slides"></div>
       <h3 class="title"></h3>
       <a class="prev">‹</a>
       <a class="next">›</a>
       <a class="close">×</a>
       <a class="play-pause"></a>
       <ol class="indicator"></ol>
   </div>  
      <div id="links">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-3">
         <a href="img/117.jpg" class="thumbnail">
             <img src="img/thumbnails/117.jpg">
         </a>
     </div>    
     <div class="col-xs-2">
         <a href="img/119.jpg" class="thumbnail">
             <img src="img/thumbnails/119.jpg">
         </a>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-2">
         <a href="img/120.jpg" class="thumbnail">
             <img src="img/thumbnails/120.jpg">
         </a>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-2">
         <a href="img/121.jpg" class="thumbnail">
             <img src="img/thumbnails/121.jpg">
         </a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-3">
         <a href="img/125.jpg" class="thumbnail">
             <img src="img/tumbnails/125.jpg">
         </a>
     </div>    
     <div class="col-xs-2">
         <a href="img/128.jpg" class="thumbnail">
             <img src="img/thumbnails/128.jpg">
         </a>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-2">
         <a href="img/129.jpg" class="thumbnail">
             <img src="img/thumbnails/129.jpg">
         </a>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-2">
         <a href="img/130.jpg" class="thumbnail">
             <img src="img/thumbnails/130.jpg">
         </a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <script>
   document.getElementById('links').onclick = function (event) {
       event = event || window.event;
       var target = event.target || event.srcElement,
           link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target,
           options = {index: link, event: event},
           links = this.getElementsByTagName('a');
       blueimp.Gallery(links, options);
   };
   </script>
```

Does anyone have an idea of what can be happening here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo: change

```
<img src="img/tumbnails/125.jpg">
```

to (add the 'h')

```
<img src="img/thumbnails/125.jpg">
```

:)

Comment: @Jorge Montoya did this solve your problem? If so, please mark it as solved.

Comment: It was so obvious, that I didn't see it. I was wondering if that had something to do with jquery or javascript. Thank you @timgavin for your help.